# DateDiff in SSIS

Tags: sql, postgresql, ssis

I want to include a datediff into my SQL Command in SSIS but I am receiving the error below:

I have done quite a bit of research but cannot seem to get the command to work, tried changing the second to ss, tried include (DT_Date), tried quotations around second and other things but not sure why it#s not working.

Does anyone know what is the correct syntax to pass the query?

```
SELECT 
  http.xxx.xxx_at AS xxx_at,
  http_xxxxx.xxxxx_at AS xxxxx_at,
DATEDIFF(second, xxx.xxx_at,http_xxxxx.xxxxx_at) As duration
FROM public.xxxxx
FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: maybe use "ss" or "s" instead of SECOND

Comment: If "ss" results in an error then what is the error? Are the dates definitely in the right format?

Comment: What is the RDBMS you are connecting to? Looks like SQL Server syntax and a postgres error message.

Comment: I am connecting to a postgreSQL database and I believe it is using ANSI sql. ss gives me the same error - column "ss" does not exist. Looking at the state number, I believe it is referencing as  is not valid in the context where it is used.

Comment: No that isn't standard SQL. Some postgres alternatives are here http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff

Comment: Do you want the difference of both timestamps in seconds or the difference of the "seconds part" of each timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Martin, there is no DATEDIFF command for postgres. The workaround is using DATE_PART:

```
((DATE_PART('day', created_at::timestamp - completed_at::timestamp) * 24 + 
                DATE_PART('hour', created_at::timestamp -completed_at::timestamp)) * 60 +
                DATE_PART('minute', created_at::timestamp - completed_at::timestamp)) * 60 +
                DATE_PART('second', created_at::timestamp -completed_at::timestamp) As Duration
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting one timestamp from another will yield [and interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) from which you can then [extract](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) the seconds:

```
extract(epoch from created_at::timestamp - completed_at::timestamp) as duration
```